# What's the difference between circular Window progress and progress bar in android

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-styles

Is there a difference between **the progress bar** and **the window progress** in android ?
How can I create a window progress because I tried that by the code below but I obtained an circular progress Bar not a window progress:

```
<ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/actionBar_progressIndicator"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:indeterminateOnly="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                style="?android:progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                />
```

this an example for a window progress:[image: window progress]

ps: I want to make it through xml way not by the java code

Comment: These are the styles to show the progress for any task in a circular or horizontal way.

Comment: But is there really a widget called "window progress" in android community ?

Comment: I think your asking to show the INDETERMINATE PROGRESS under the header bar.
It can be achieve by calling following in onCreate():
`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
`
To show:
`setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
setProgressBarVisibility(true);
`
and hide it as:
` setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
  setProgressBarVisibility(false);`.

Comment: @jitainsharma thank you but for my case I can't make that with java code.I want to make it with xml

Answer (score 0):

For adding the progress bar in xml:

```
 <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@animator/progressbar_animation"
             />
```

Where indeterminateDrawable is the animation used to display the custom progress image, you can make it default just by applying the style.